# Regexpression - mutliline in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have an arbitray string, e.g.

```
String multiline=`
This is my "test" case
with lines
\section{new section}
Another incorrect test"
\section{next section}
With some more "text"
\subsection{next section}
With some more "text1"
`
```

I use LaTeX and I want to replace the quotes with those which are used in books - similar to ,, and ´´ For this I need to replace the beginning quotes with a `\glqq` and the ending with a `\qrqq` - for each group which starts with `\.?section`.

If I try the following

```
String pattern1 = "(^\\\\.?section\\{.+\\})[\\s\\S]*(\\\"(.+)\\\")";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern1, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
System.out.println(p.matcher(testString).find()); //true

while (m.find()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Index: " + i);
    System.out.println(m.group(i).replaceAll("\"([\\w]+)\"", "\u00AB$1\u00BB"));
  }
}
```

I get as a result on the console

```
true
Index: 0
\section{new section}
Another incorrect test"
\section{next section}
With some more «text1»
Index: 1
\section{new section}
Index: 2
«text1»
Index: 3
text1
```

My some problems with the current approach:

1. The first valid match (`"text"`) isn't found. I guess it has to do with the mulitline and incorrect grouping of `\section{`. The grouping for the quotes should be restricted to a group which starts with `\section` and ends with `\?.section` - how to make this correct?
2. Even when the text is found properly - how to get a complete string with the replacements?

Comment: "for each group which starts with \section": what makes such a group stop? Is it just when another group starts?

Comment: Yeah - it stops with the next start. Seems like I didn't make it clear :-/ Except the very last group - which doesn't have a `\section`

Comment: Take a look on LaTeX solution to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38985/replace-quotes-with-quotes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The LaTeX solution doesn't much help since I still have the problem to replace the beginng and end quotes with some other string (e.g. `\beginquote`). I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: Please check https://ideone.com/Nujqt3 - do you want something of the kind?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: If you would transform it into an answer with the code, I'll accept it. Thx very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match all texts between `section` and the next `section` or end of string, and replace all `"..."` strings inside it with `«...`.

Here is the Java snippet (see [demo](https://ideone.com/Nujqt3)):

```
String s = "This is my \"test\" case\nwith lines\n\\section{new section}\nAnother incorrect test\"\n\\section{next section}\nWith some more \"text\"\n\\subsection{next section}\nWith some more \"text1\"";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)section.*?(?=section|$)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String out = m.group(0).replaceAll("\"([^\"]*)\"", "«$1»");
    m.appendReplacement(result, Matcher.quoteReplacement(out));
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Output:

```
This is my "test" case
with lines
\section{new section}
Another incorrect test"
\section{next section}
With some more «text»
\subsection{next section}
With some more «text1»
```

The pattern means:

- `(?s)` - `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option
- `section` - a `section` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=section|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires a `section` substring or end of string to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thx this helps definitly. Just out of curiosity for the second lookup: Why a `([^\"]*)` instead of a simple `(.+)`. What's the benefit?

Comment: @LeO [`.+`](https://regex101.com/r/jkMfMZ/1) matches 1 or more chars as many as possible. [`[^"]*`](https://regex101.com/r/jkMfMZ/2) matches 0 or more chars other than `"`.

Comment: If I want to match only what is word bound, ie. starting `"` should be before a word starts and ending `"` should be after a word ended - what to use? (I don't want to find anything like `Te"st"ing`! Using `\b` for word boundary, i.e. `\\b\"([^\"]*)\"\\b` just matches the second `"`

Comment: @LeO You may try `.replaceAll("\\B\"\\b([^\"]*)\\b\"\\B", "«$1»")`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RJZebm/1)

Comment: Thx a lot. After some struggle I opened another - independent q because I thought its better to track it differently. I found the solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60821016/325868). Some cases are not matched with approach but any thx!

Comment: @LeO I posted the answer there. `.replaceAll("\\B\"\\b(.*?)\\b\"\\B", "\\\\q{$1}")`