# Java: RegExp for matching words between a quote

Tags: java, regex

I have the following test string

```
This is my "te

st" case
with lines for "tes"t"ing" with regex
But as he said "It could be an arbitrary number of words"
```

And I want to match everything which is between `"` as long as it is bound to words. I have the following regexp:

```
\"([^\"]*)\"
```

which matches quite well the words of `"test"` even if its split apart. Is there a way to find a `tes"t"ing` as well a whole word (and not split apart into two words? Trying with the word boundaries `\b` (`\b\"([^\"]*)\"\b`) doesn't work very well because it won't match the very first `"` nor the just mentioned group.

I need it for Java regexp.

**UPDATE**
As a result I need to have

```
This is my \q{te

st} case
with lines for \q{tes"t"ing} with regex
But as he said \q{It could be an arbitrary number of words}
```

Comment: Given the example in your question. What would be the desired output?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've updated now.

Comment: “bound to words” is unclear as you evidently wish to match `”te          st”` but that is not a word (is not comprised entirely of word characters). What about `”te   x    st”`? Do you wish to match `b` in `a”b”`?

Comment: `te x ting` should be matched while `a"b test` should be ignored, ie `a"b "Test"` should match `"Test"` only. matching empty would be great as well. Honestly I didn't test all the cases. But I need to have it for Java definitely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
.replaceAll("\\B\"\\b(.*?)\\b\"\\B", "\\\\q{$1}")
```

Or, if the matches may span across multiple lines, add `(?s)` modifier:

```
.replaceAll("(?s)\\B\"\\b(.*?)\\b\"\\B", "\\\\q{$1}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EclEVb/1) .

**Details**

- `\B"\b` - a `"` that is either at the start of the string or preceded with a non-word char, and that is followed with a word char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\b"\B` - a `"` that is either at the end of the string or followed with a non-word char, and that is preceded with a word char.

The replacement is a backslash (`"\\\\"`, note the double literal backslash is necessary in the regex replacement part to insert a real, literal backslash since a backslash is a special char in the replacement pattern), `q{`, the Group1  value (`$1`) and a `}`.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Drvxse):

```
String s = "This is my \"te\n\nst\" case\nwith lines for \"tes\"t\"ing\" with regex\nBut as he said \"It could be an arbitrary number of words\"";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\B\"\\b(.*?)\\b\"\\B", "\\\\q{$1}"));
```

Output:

```
This is my "te

st" case
with lines for \q{tes"t"ing} with regex
But as he said \q{It could be an arbitrary number of words}
```

**NOTE:**

If you also need to match two consecutive double quotes that are not preceded, nor followed with word characters, you can modify the above regular expression the following way:

```
 .replaceAll("(?s)\\B(\"\\b(.*?)\\b\"|\"\")\\B", "\\\\q{$2}")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EclEVb/2).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - an embedded flag option (equal to `Pattern.DOTALL`) that makes `.` match line break chars, too
- `\B` - a non-word boundary, here, it means that immediately to the left, there must be a non-word char or start of string (because after `\B`, there is  a non-word char, `"`)
- `(` - start of the first capturing group:

  - `"\b(.*?)\b"` - `"` followed with a word char, then Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars, as few as possible, and then a `"` that is preceded with a word char (that is why this pattern can't match `""`, since after the first and before the second, there must be a letter, digit or `_`)
  - `|` - or
  - `""` - a `""` substring
- `)` - end of the first capturing group
- `\B` - a non-word boundary, here, it means that immediately to the right, there must be a non-word char or end of string (because before `\B`, there is  a non-word char, `"`).

Comment: I'm honestly confused about the explanation of `(.*?)` because to my understandig if there is not text included it should match as well. But won't e.g. `this is "" quote`

Comment: @LeO `.*?` matches *any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible*. That is correct. But since `\B"\b` requires a word char after `"`, the whole regex can't match `""`.

Comment: You may wish add `(?s)` at the “regex demo” link or move the link above “Or, if the...”.

Comment: @LeO I added the explanation to your edit. Have a good day, and lots of health to you and your family!

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex that used lookbehind and lookahead to ensure that previous and next characters is not a non-whitespace character:

```
(?<!\S)".*?"(?!\S)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yIgUsA/2)

Adding helpful comment from OP which worked to solve the problem which was a bit more than what was mentioned in question:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?s)(?<!\\S)\"(.*?)\"(?!\\S)", "\\\\q{$1}");
```

Comment: Time shift... I'll test it soon... Not sure how it'll work in Java

Comment: The very first approach works very well in Java. After some struggle I figured out that I need some additional grouping. With this it works very well, i.e. `replaceAll("((?<!\\S)\")(.*?)(\"(?!\\S))", "\\\\q{$2}");` Shall I update your answer and than accept? Or you want to update it? Thx a lot!

Comment: However, I'd recommend using (non)-word boundaries as whitespace boundaries miss the matches right after/before punctuation. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60828662/3832970).

Comment: Note that this does not match `b` in `a”b”`.

Comment: As per the originally problem it wasn't supposed to match `"b"` in `a"b"` and it is clearly mentioned in my answer also.

Comment: The OP said, 'And I want to match everything which is between " as long as it is bound to words.'. There is no mention of what may precede the beginning double-quote or follow the ending one. You'll see that I've asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the regular expression

```
(?<=\")(?:[a-z]+\"[a-z]+\"[a-z]+|[a-z][^"]+)(?=\")
```

with the case-indifferent flag `i` (or preface with `(?i)`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PvZbm5/2/)

As seen at the link this regex matches the following three substrings of the text given in the question:

```
te                                                                    st
tes"t"ing
It could be an arbitrary number of words
```

​
The regex engine performs the following operations:

```
(?<=\")    # match a double-quote in a positive lookbehind
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  [a-z]+\" # match 1+ letters, then a double-quote
  [a-z]+\" # match 1+ letters, then a double-quote
  [a-z]+   # match 1+ letters
  |        # or
  [a-z]    # match 1 letter
  [^"]+    # match 1+ characters other than a double-quote
)          # end non-capture group
(?=\")     # match a double-quote in a positive lookahead
```